Fractional scaling and "wasted" monitor real estate
Ubuntu 22.04.4, gnome shell 42.9, wayland.
I have two monitors, I set the fractional scaling on each to be 125%.
On the left monitor, I have an icon on the desktop appearing in the middle of the monitor.  I can move it around on that monitor, but:  Something strange happens if I try to move it to one of the three rightmost "columns" of that left monitor.  If I try to move it to one of those three rightmost columns on the left monitor, it ends up in one of the three leftmost columns of the right monitor.  (But:  Attempting to place an icon in one of the three leftmost columns of the right monitor does NOT place it in one of the three rightmost columns of the left monitor - In this case the icon stays on the right monitor where I intend for it to be.)
Did not have this problem with scaling at 100%.
Why is this happening?
How do I fix this problem?
UPDATE -
I stumbled across this information:
I have the resolution on each monitor to be 1920 X 1080.  When I leave the fractional scaling - under the Ubuntu settings display option - at the default of 100%, in the monitors.xml file the x,y coordinates for the two monitors are exactly as I'd expect them to be:  viz., 0,0 for the left monitor, and 1920,0 for the right monitor.  However, when I change that fractional scaling setting from 100% to 125% on each monitor, and leave the resolution on each monitor at 1920 X 1080, the x,y coordinates automatically get changed to 0,0 and 1536,0.  My simplistic understanding is that this change effectively makes the left monitor get cutoff at 1536 instead of at 1920, basically moving the rightmost 20% of that monitor to be treated as part of the right monitor.  If I manually fix the x,y coordinates in the monitors.xml file, then at next reboot the fractional scaling is automatically reset to 100% on each monitor. I obviously do not understand the relationship between fractional scaling and monitor dimensions in the monitors.xml file.  (Incidentally, in gnome tweaks under the font setting I have throughout left the scaling option at the default of 1.0.  Don't know how, if at all, that interacts with the fractional scaling in the Ubuntu settings.)

What do you mean by columns on the monitor?

@David , thanks for responding.  I knew my description would be a problem.  If you think of a grid overlaid on the monitor, and each desktop icon fits into a single cell within that grid, what I'm trying to describe is that I am unable to place a desktop icon in that region of the left monitor that is equivalent to the three rightmost virtual columns of that imaginary grid.  Sorry, I don't know how better to describe it.  Make sense?

@David , you'll note that I added an update to my original post above.
